# a simple inequality on the simplex

Tags: probability, inequality

Could anyone help me to show:

For any $v=(v_1,v_2), v_i\ge 0, \sum_{i=1}^{2} v_i=1$ one has $\sum_{i=1}^{2} v_i|\bar p_i-\bar p|\le\sum_{i=1}^{1}\sum_{j=i+1}^{2}\frac{v_i+v_j}{2} |\bar p_i-\bar p_j|$ where $\bar p=\sum_{j=1}^{2}v_j\bar p_j, \bar p_j\in [0,1]\forall j=1,2.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename $p_i = \bar{p}_i$, so $\bar{p} = \sum_{i=1}^3 v_i p_i.$
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^3 v_i |p_i - \bar{p}| &= \sum_{i=1}^3 v_i \left|  \sum_{j=1}^3 p_i v_j - \bar{p}\right| \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^3 v_i \left| \sum_{j \neq i} v_j( p_i - p_j)\right| \\
&\leq \sum_{i=1}^3 v_i\left(\sum_{j\neq i} |p_i - p_j|\right)\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^2 \sum_{j=i+1}^3 \frac{v_i+v_j}{2}|p_i - p_j|. 
\end{align*}

Comment: Edited. $ \; $ $ \; $